# How to represent formatted printf using echo in bash

Tags: linux, bash, printf, echo, formatted-text

What is a command that produces the same output as formatted printf in bash

Comment: why do u "need to avoid using `printf`"?

Comment: Quite the contrary, you should use `printf` to avoid using `echo`.

Comment: `printf` automatically loops until all arguments are consumed. Do you have to emulate this behavior too?

Comment: you need to type `$'\n'` and `$'\t'` to use them in echo

Comment: @diggusbickus No, you don't. You can use `-e` (or you can set the necessary options to make `echo` behave in a POSIX-compliant fashion). `$'...'` is more useful for defining strings used in other contests, like assignments and arguments to commands that don't do their own escape processing.

Comment: Your `printf` command provides a format but no corresponding arguments.  Are we supposed to assume that you want something to which you can feed the three additional arguments that the given command would accommodate?

Comment: `cat <<<"printf 'sometext %s \t %s\n %s\n'"` will produce the same output as shown in the question. Although I propose to close the question as unclear, need debugging details. User did not provide enough detail on what is expected or an explanation for the dismiss of `printf`. Such reality impracticable questions are often part of homework exercises. The question as-is also offers no help to other visitors. Nobody is gonna dismiss `printf` without a reason. If there is a reason, it must be mentioned and explicit.

Comment: @LéaGris I am trying to demonstrate different types of printing methods in shell for a totally different purpose, and I thought I can get some help here since I read before that both methods are the same but I didn't know how echo can be formatted as printf.

Comment: @pynexj I totally agree that print is more powerful in this case and I post this question to just know if there is any possibility to use them interchangeably. Thank you

Comment: @Socowi can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: @mfmarb If you don't know what I meant you probably don't need it. The printf in posix shells like bash features an implicit loop: `printf a%s 1 2 3` prints `a1a2a3` even though the format string contains only one `%s` and one `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `echo` on your System supporting `-ne` then you can define a function like...

```
$ puts(){(echo -ne "sometext ${1}\t ${2}\n ${3}\n")}
$ puts hello world bye
sometext hello   world
 bye
```

( Typed in a bash )

For looping through the List of Arguments this is possible...

```
puts(){
for string in ${@}; do
 echo -ne ${string}
done
}
```

Than you can do...

```
puts 0 1 "\n" 3 "\t" 4 5 6 "\n" 7 8 9 "\n"
```

Comment: Note that the subshell `( )` is unneeded here. But if you remove these parens, a semicolon and spaces around the braces are required→ `puts() { echo -ne "…"; }`

Comment: Note that this is not 100% equivalent. `echo -e "$1"` interprets escape sequences inside `$1` too, while `printf %s\\n "$1"` does not. Also, `printf` loops until all arguments are consumed.

Comment: @Socowi - When ```\n``` is escaped with a second Backslash then ```echo -n "sometext\\n"``` put also out the ```\n``` and not a Newline. And ```echo -n``` means: Do not automatically add a Newline and do not interpret ```\n``` or ```\t```. Try it by yourself. I use ```echo -n >filename``` normally to empty a file without adding a Newline. So the File is empty with exact 0 Byte of Size. So ```-ne``` means: Interpret ```\n``` and/or ```\t``` but do not add automatically a Newline.

Comment: This wasn't my point at all. I used a simplified command and a general case for illustration. Seems like that was counterproductive, so here is a concrete example (with a more traditional quoting style. I think you misinterpreted the `\\n` too): Compare `puts '\n' 2 3 4 5 6` and `printf 'sometext %s \t %s\n %s\n' '\n' 2 3 4 5 6`.

Comment: OK. I see and agree. I put an enhancement to my Post thats loop through the List of Arguments. But one Thing is: Dont use single Quotes ;-)

Comment: ^--> Joking - That will work too: ```puts '0 1 \n 3 \t 4 5 6 \n 7 8 9 \n'```